# Create thread in Microsoft Teams with Subject

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently trying to create a Microsoft teams thread (within a channel) via the Microsoft Graph API.
I'd like thread to have a subject/title and I'm sending the following request (from the graph explorer)
`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/chatThreads`
with the following payload

```
{
    "rootMessage": {
        "body": {
            "contentType": 1,
            "content": "<h1>Hello world</h1>"
        },
        "subject": "Welcome Aboard!"
    }
}
```

However the thread that gets created doesn't have any title as you can see on the following screen capture.
[image: chat thread with no subject]
So the question is: **how can I create a chat thread with a subject from the Microsoft Graph API?**

Edit: here is the payload I get for the message "title from teams" (which was created from the UI), note is contains a subject attribute.

```
{
            "replyToId": null,
            "etag": "1537198542791",
            "messageType": "message",
            "createdDateTime": "2018-09-17T15:35:42.791Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": null,
            "deleted": false,
            "subject": "title from teams",
            "summary": null,
            "importance": "normal",
            "locale": "en-us",
            "id": "1537198542791",
            "from": {
                "application": null,
                "device": null,
                "user": {
                    "id": "c2e8df37-c6a7-4d88-89b1-feb4f1fda7c5",
                    "displayName": "Vincent Biret",
                    "identityProvider": "Aad"
                }
            },
            "body": {
                "contentType": "text",
                "content": "wvwvwevw"
            },
            "attachments": [],
            "mentions": [],
            "reactions": []
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "subject" for a post in Microsoft Teams. These are chat threads, not email threads. The only content is the `body`:

```
{
  "rootMessage": {
      "body": {
        "contentType": 1,
        "content": "<h1>Hello world</h1>"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I interpreted the similar fields and the root message property name as the type of the root message is in fact a chat message. And then thought I could use those properties as well. Then am I right to think there's no way today from the graph to create a thread with a subject or with mentions? This is very limiting. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/chatMessage

Comment: Teams is not an email platform, those are all email centric features.

Comment: I'm confused, in teams (web or client) you can set a subject for a new thread (see screen shot) as well as mention people. How can you do that through the API?

Comment: That isn't a subject/title, that is just part of the message rapped in an HTML Heading tag `<h1>string</h1>`.

Comment: I added the payload for the message "title from teams" which was created from the UI. Note that I get a subject attribute, and the subject is not a h1 tag in the body.